# Not able to create Custom Open Graph Stories using FB SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to post story via my app using Graph API of facebook SDK.
I have configured actions and object and story on its App console, and have implemented following code to achieve the same.

```
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"];
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImageURL:imageURL userGenerated:NO];
    NSDictionary *properties = @{
                                 @"og:type": @"abc-holdings:glc",
                                 @"og:title": @"Sample GLC",
                                 @"og:description": @"Test Geo",
                                 @"og:url": @"http://samples.ogp.me/147425295593678",
                                 @"og:image": @[photo],
                                 @"abc-holdings:location:longitude":@(-58.381667),
                                 @"abc-holdings:location:latitude":@(23.381667)
                                 };
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction actionWithType:@"abc-holdings:has_a_glc" object:object key:@"glc"];
    [action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];


    // Create the content
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"glc";

    // Share the content
    FBSDKShareAPI *shareAPI = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc] init];
    shareAPI.shareContent = content;
    shareAPI.delegate = self;

    [shareAPI share];
```

But this issue is that it respond me as below

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=201 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 201.)" UserInfo=0x7fb9e1749190 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Error sharing Open Graph content, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb9e14c5210 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)"}
```

Is there any idea to anyone regarding this ?

Comment: This is exactly the problem I'm having... Any luck solving it?

Comment: Try by appending the namespace to the type `glc` and see if that helps. e.g. `[ ... object:object key:@"abc-holdings:glc"]` and `content.previewPropertyName = @"abc-holdings:glc";`.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your app at Facebook. Choose Open Graph settings, choose your action type, scroll down till the end. There you will see some checkboxes [Your action capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJUL1.png)

Check last checkbox and try to share your content again.